# how to push to github under a different username every time

Tags: git, github, terminal

```
git push https://github.com/YusupovSamandar/Pubg.git master
remote: Permission to YusupovSamandar/Pubg.git denied to SamandarYusupov.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/YusupovSamandar/Pubg.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I created new github account and when i pushed my repo this error happened

Then i removed my github account with git config --global `credential.helper ""`
Now when i want to push to github, git is asking for username and password every time.

So is there any way i can totally change my git settings to my new account so that git would newer ask type error or ask username and password every time

Comment: What was the value of `credential.helper`? If it was `manager` and you are using Windows, the username and password are stored in Windows Credential Manager. You can just edit them. If it was `store`, they are stored in a local file, like `~/.git-credentials`. You can also edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to change the credentials stored in your credential manager, then make sure you re-enable your credential manager, and follow the steps outlined [to do that in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager):

> Usually, if the password or token is invalid, Git will erase it and prompt for a new one. However, there are times when this doesn’t always happen. To change the password or token, you can erase the existing credentials and then Git will prompt for new ones. To erase credentials, use a syntax like the following (substituting your username and the hostname):
>
> ```
> $ echo url=https://author@git.example.org | git credential reject
> ```

If your question is how to use two different accounts with the same site, then [that question is also answered in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingHTTP):

> Usually the easiest way to distinguish between these accounts is to use the username in the URL. For example, if you have the accounts author and committer on git.example.org, you can use the URLs https://author@git.example.org/org1/project1.git and https://committer@git.example.org/org2/project2.git. This way, when you use a credential helper, it will automatically try to look up the correct credentials for your account. If you already have a remote set up, you can change the URL with something like `git remote set-url origin https://author@git.example.org/org1/project1.git` (see `git-remote(1)` for details).

There's also [an answer for SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH).